# Xcode 6.1.1 crash exporting Ad Hoc ipa

Tags: xcode, ipa, adhoc

I've a problem exporting an iPhone archive for Ad Hoc distribution.
Reading another discussion, it seemed to be a certificate or distribution profile problem. So I created a new certificate and a new distribution profile and deleted the old, but it didn't solved the problem: Xcode still keep crashing.

Here's the first lines of the problem:

```html
Process:               Xcode [380]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               6.1.1 (6611)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-6611000000000000~4
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       810788292
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [380]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2015-01-06 17:57:35.836 +0100
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10 (14A389)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        80C884D6-4BDC-3E20-850A-44F38C3E5491


Time Awake Since Boot: 260 seconds

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 6A2008a
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks-6611/IDEFoundation/Distribution/IDEDistributionProvisioning.m:34
Details:  Assertion failed: [rootDistributionItems count] > 0
Object:   <IDEDistributionProvisioning: 0x7fbdb6ed49d0>
Method:   -initWithRootDistributionItems:distributionMethod:teamID:codesignableDevicesOrNil:logging:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fbdb24389c0>{number = 1, name = main}
Hints:   None
```

The "Assertion failed: [rootDistributionItem count] > 0" suggests me that Xcode is unable to find a distribution profile. Did someone get the same problem?

Moreover, I tried to export the ipa using a command in the terminal:

```html
xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath 'AppName 06-01-15 17.49.xcarchive' -exportPath AppName -exportFormat ipa -exportProvisioningProfile "AppName_AdHoc"
```

The ipa is generated successfully, but if I try to install it on my iPhone with iTunes, it keep being "Installing..."

Any help would be appreciated
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Today I tried to create a new simple app (single view application). I created the archive and exported it to IPA for ad hoc distribution without any problem.

So the issue should be in my project, and not with certificates or profiles.

EDIT: I upgraded the Deployment target to iOS6 and that solved the problem!